# Отсутствующие запятые и опечатки в описаниях Знаков

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Как известно, [если причастный оборот стоит после определяемого слова, он выделяется запятыми с двух сторон](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B9_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.82). Деепричастные обороты выделяются запятыми почти всегда.

#### Для следующих [Знаков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) это правило не выполнено:

- *Замечанный вопрос* (еще и опечатка, должно быть *Замеч`е`нный*)
  Задал вопрос`,` получивший 1000 просмотров
- *Известный вопрос*
  Задал вопрос`,` получивший 2500 просмотров
- *Знаменитый вопрос*
  Задал вопрос`,` получивший 10 000 просмотров
- *Партсобрание*
  Участвовал в выборах на любом из активных этапов`,` имея достаточно высокую репутацию для голосования

#### И просто опечатки:

- *Некромант*
  Ответил на вопрос с `рейтингом` 5 и более баллов спустя 60 дней и более
- *Констебль*
  Выполнял обязанности временного модератора не менее 1 года или во время `получения степени` "зрелого" сайта
- *Дисциплинированный*
  Удалил свое сообщение с `рейтингом` 3 или более балла

---

*Вот `так` выше выделено то, как должно быть по моему мнению.*

Comment: Спасибо за замечания! Поправили!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Большое спасибо!